# Help test the Alpha version of the StackExchange Android App

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

This is a cross post from meta.SO:

[Help us test the alpha version of our Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app)

To register for alpha testing [sign up here](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/forms/d/1DW1zNni6WHbOc1lorFK-lFvP3RSeCUaQAf-OVaAyHso/viewform).

After you register we will send you an invite to a private Google community where you can find a link to download our app directly from the Google Play store.  The invitations will be sent out in waves, so if you don’t get an invite immediately, be patient.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Bryan! I may add that the "private Google community" is bound to G+ -- so people like me (avoiding most of those "social stuff" like G+, Facebook, etc.) are out of luck here.

Comment: @Izzy this is the way that "private beta channels" work on the Play Store. I'm on the beta channel for a couple of other apps and have needed to join either a G+ or Google Groups community to switch to the beta channel on each of them. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: @Izzy That's what fake accounts are for.  Link it to nothing, use it for one thing, abandon it.

Comment: Signed up! :) Cheers for that :)

Comment: @MatthewRead doesn't help that much with the "fake account". Both come to the same device (ah, same person *Match!*) I might seem a little paranoid, but I don't like using that stuff. I'm in real trouble when Google decides to integrate their playstore app with G+, and let the original app die (as it did with Latitude)...

Comment: @Izzy Ah, true enough. I haven't created a G+ account for my main email and now I can't leave app reviews, very annoying.

Comment: Exactly. At the time the G+ account became mandatory for reviews, I stopped posting them on Play. I switched over to AppBrain (much more comfortable), and let GreaseMonkey/Scriptish take care against "mis-steps" with my [Android AppLinks Rewriter](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/174113) :)

Comment: Signed Up, waiting for the invite :-)

Comment: FYI: it appears invites went out today. (I got one, and I'm seeing Meta.SO posts in the android-app tag for the first time.)

Comment: Still no invite. :(

Comment: Same here, still waiting for an invite :(

Comment: My guess is they are rolling them out so many at a time, so not everyone is testing the first version at once and then forget about it.

Comment: I applied about over a week ago as soon as I saw Bryan's post, and just got my invite 10 minutes ago, so if you've applied and think they've forgotten/ignoring you, don't worry. Looking at the group membership I think there's only 35 of us signed up to test right now (including a couple of names I recognized from AE), so it looks like they're rolling access out slowly at the moment.

Comment: Got the alpha download this morning too. :)

Comment: @geffchang lucky you... still waiting for the invite..

Comment: @t0mm13 Don't worry. You'll probably get it soon. :)

Comment: Hmm, devices running CM because they don't have an OTA 4.3 update will still get the app, *right*?

Comment: BTW, the notifications for this app are what I've always dreamed of having :)

Comment: @BryanDenny At the moment, I find them annoying. I wish there was a setting to turn them off. Sometimes it's weird too. I've already read the notifications on the PC. But later, I still get notifications about them.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ I think if your device is running CM - forget it... that's my gut feeling, I put it down as having JB but its CM and no invite :(

Comment: @t0mm13b **NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO** *deep breath* **OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOHH**